# My hangman game displays more dashes "-" than supposed to

Tags: c#

im new to programming and am currently challanging myself by creating a hangman game, i have written a little bit of code that takes a word, divides it into a char array, takes an answer and display the answers.. The problem is each time the for loop runs in main, more dashes "-" keep appearing.

Thanks to people in advance for answering, happpy coding :)

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Hangman
{
    class Funk
    {
        public char[] Word = new char[20];
        public char[] GuessedLetters = new char[20];
        public string HiddenWord = "-";

        public string GetHiddenWord()
        {

            for (int i = 1; i < Word.Length; i++) {
                HiddenWord += "-";
            }

            return HiddenWord;
        }

        public bool IsAnswerCorrect()
        {
            if ( 10 == 10)
            {
                return true;
            }

            else 
            {
                return false; 
            }


        }

        public void SetGuessedLetters(char answer, int value) 
        {
            GuessedLetters[value] = answer;
        }

       

        public Funk(string word) 
        {
            Word = word.ToCharArray();
            
        }


    }
}
```

```html
using System;

namespace Hangman
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Get word and set word
            //Write Word as hidden
            //take letter as guess
            //Hangman mechaniks

            bool GameOver = false;
            int NumberOfGuesses = 6;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Word");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Clear();

            Funk funk = new Funk(name);

            while (GameOver == false) {
                for (int i = 0; i < funk.Word.Length; i++) {
                    Console.WriteLine(funk.GetHiddenWord());
                    Console.WriteLine("Guess away, you have " + NumberOfGuesses + " guesses left");

                    Console.WriteLine("Answers:" + funk.GuessedLetters[0] + funk.GuessedLetters[1] + funk.GuessedLetters[2] + funk.GuessedLetters[3]
                                                    + funk.GuessedLetters[4] + funk.GuessedLetters[5] + funk.GuessedLetters[6] + funk.GuessedLetters[7]);


                    char answer = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
                    funk.SetGuessedLetters(answer, i);
                    


                    Console.Clear();
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Each time you call `Funk.GetHiddenWord`, a number of dashes is appended to `Funk.HiddenWord`. You start with one dash and end up with `1+Word.Length*n` after `n` rounds of your main loop. You need to do that only once to initialize.

Answer (score 1):

Put the initialisation `HiddenWord = "-";` inside the `GetHiddenWord()` method:

```
    public string GetHiddenWord()
    {

        HiddenWord = "-"; // init every time here
        for (int i = 1; i < Word.Length; i++) {
            HiddenWord += "-";
        }

        return HiddenWord;
    }
```

Effectively if you dont re-initialise the `HiddenWord` to be empty again, you append more dashes.

Comment: Omg youre a genius finding the solution with so limited information, thx brother

Comment: @LukasAskolin Thanks, if it solves your problem, you can accept the answer